# How to change the root directory using a Script?

Tags: linux, root, links

I wanted to change the root directory for a user after running a script,

for example :

someone uses source on a script

when he uses `cd /` instead of going to the `root` directory he goes to `/custom_root/dir`

can that be done, and if so how?

to be clear, I want to change `/` from pointing to the `root` directory it points to a different directory and `ln` is not an option

,thank you

Comment: What's your purpose? If you want to deny access to `/`, this is not a right way. Or maybe you want to trick somebody and lure them to another directory? A shell function might do what you want. It's not possible to declare a function in your current shell by running a script; it's possible to do it by *sourcing*. There's also `chroot` command. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski  yes using the `source` command is my purpose and yes, I want them in another directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [chroot](https://wiki.debian.org/chroot) for this purpose. Also here's an answer to another question's answer that explains what's chroot and how it's used to jail users
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105/chroot-jail-what-is-it-and-how-do-i-use-it